# Use of ReplyKeyboardMarkup in method triggered by CallbackQueryHandler in python-telegram-bot based bot

Tags: python-telegram-bot

In my Python-telegram-bot package-based program, there's a method named `params_set` containing the following code:

```
def params_set(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    query = update.callback_query
    custom_keyboard = []
    for i in range(10):
        custom_keyboard.append([KeyboardButton(str(i))])
    reply_markup = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(custom_keyboard, one_time_keyboard=True)
    update.message.reply_text("Some text", reply_markup=reply_markup)
```

The issue arises because the `params_set` method is triggered by a `CallbackQueryHandler`, causing `update.message` to be `None`. To resolve this, I need to replace `update.message.reply_text` with `query.edit_message_text` and include the `reply_markup` parameter.

However, when I attempt to call:

```
query.edit_message_text("Some text", reply_markup=reply_markup)
```

next error occur:

```
Can't parse inline keyboard button: text buttons are unallowed in the inline keyboard
```

Question: Is it possible to use `ReplyKeyboardMarkup` in `CallbackQueryHandler` triggered method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Editing keyboards is [only supported](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#updating-messages) with inline keyboards
`ReplyKeyboardMarkup` can only be used when sending a new messages
For handling callback queries, this means that you can use `ReplyKeyboardMarkup` only if you send a new message as result of the `CallbackQuery`. This can e.g. be done via `context.bot.send_message` or `update.callback_query.message.reply_text` (or `update.effective_message.reply_text`, which is equivalent). Note that the latter can only work if `update.callback_query.message` is accessible.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.